# About object's property name

Tags: javascript, oop

How to add a property to an object when the property name come from a var?

```
var obj={};
var propName="realName";
obj.propName; //wrong
obj."realName"; //wrong
```

Comment: Hey, I remember that object behave like array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html):

```
var obj = {};
var propName = "realName";
obj[propName] = "foo";  // Same as `obj.realName = "foo";`
```