# What is the correct way to add a property to an Object [Typescript]

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I'm learning `typescript`. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490146/about-objects-property-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841677/unable-to-add-new-properties-to-an-object-literal-using-typescript/57841947#57841947). I tried many other solutions. I have a variable `incomingArticleObject` and that variable should be of type `Object` and that `Object` should have a property `content` where `content` is of type `String`. This is what I've written:

```
export class OptionsPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  incomingArticleObject : Object = { 
                            content: String };

  constructor(...) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.incomingArticleObject = this._articleService.getClickedArticle();
    document.querySelector('#mydiv').innerHTML=this.incomingArticleObject.content; <=== ERROR
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error for that one line in `ngOnInit`:

> Property 'content' does not exist on type 'Object'.

I tried creating an `interface` also and then assigning the value like this:

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';
import ...

export interface MyObject {}

@Component({
  ...
})
export class OptionsPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  incomingArticleObject : MyObject = { 
                            content: String };

  constructor(...) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.incomingArticleObject = this._articleService.getClickedArticle();
    document.querySelector('#data-container').innerHTML=this.incomingArticleObject.content;
  }
}
```

But still I'm getting same errror with lots of red underlined code in `vs code`. Please correct me.

Comment: Name the interface something other than `Object`. Eg: `export interface IArticle {...}`. Then `incomingArticleObject : IArticle = {...}`

Comment: @adiga. I tried. I 've edited the code in my question also. Its not working. I appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: What is not working? In the first you have set the object to `{ content: String }`. This is an object literal and not a type definition. `String` is a global object. So, you're probably getting the error when you assign it to `innerHTML`. In the second, you are probably getting error in `{ content: content }` because there is no `content` identifier in the scope. Please post the exact error to create a [mcve]

Comment: In 2nd example you are setting content property to a variable named content. Where does that variable come from?

Comment: I made some changes. Instaed of global `Object` now I'm using a user defined `MyObject`. But still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: you should declare your variable like this incomingArticleObject : MyObject;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably do something like this :

```
incomingArticleObject: { content?: string } = { content: '' };
```

where

- `incomingArticleObject` is the name of your property
- `?` to make the property optional
- `:` is the marker for typing.
- `{ content?: string }` is the type of your property, an object with one property `content` which expect to be a `string`
- `=` is the marker for affectation
- `{ content: '' }` an object with one property `content` initialize with empty `string`

note that affection is optional, if you don't do it, then your property have the value `undefined` and `undefined` type doesn't have the property `content`.

Comment: But now I'm getting error for `this.incomingArticleObject` .It says:

 The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Property 'content' is missing in type 'Object' but required in type '{ content: string; }'.`

Comment: @Tanzeel In case you don't assign any values, make the content property optional. You can do this by using `{ content?: string }`

Comment: @angela. Oh no. My bad. I was using `?` with `string?` as in `{ content: string? }`